# Slow scrolling with ScrollPane

Tags: java, eclipse, draw2d

I have been using draw2d library (not GEF) and ScrollPane. The figure
presented in this ScrollPane is a kind of diagram with some Rectangles
and Connections and the scrolling is ok, but for big diagram it is very
slowly. Without the connections everything is enough fast. How can it be
done, that the scrolling goes fast also with connections used ?

The solution with scrolling some kind of an image is not applicable,
because the user can do some modifications on the diagram, so the bounds
of figures are set and Rectangles change the positions.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If the connections that you mention are a database connections, then could you reuse the connections to create a faster process ?
Also, one way of knowing which is causing the delay is to profile the application and know about the bottleneck for sure.